# analytics.sagepay.com ssl invalid certificate

Tags: android, ssl, opayo

I am using  sage latest version v3 sage pay server.

I have noticed that on android version 4.4.2 and below, if you are using  default web browser (  one shipped with android not chrome  or third party ) the user gets a invalid ssl certificate popup message.when I looked at details tab and  it  refers to analytics.sagepay.com .

This only happens on android version 4.4.4 and below.

According to www.ssllabs.com. it gives analytics.sagepay.com ssl rating of F.

It says This server's certificate chain is incomplete .Could  this be the reason.Can Some one from Sage pay please have a look at this  as  i am missing quite a few sales here.

regards

irfan

Comment: Yes, the incomplete certificate chain is the cause for Android to show the certificate warning -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222877/ios-allowed-invalid-certificate-while-android-did-not/33226837#33226837. If you want this fixed by Sage Pay, consider contacting them via their contact details on their website or their social networking channels. I'm pretty sure they are not going to crawl through StackOverflow looking for comments.

Comment: You'd be wrong, Anand Bhat :-)