# Ajax requests blocked in Android app

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, ssl, https

I created an app via cordova/PhoneGap is loaded and running successfully on PlayStore.
This app performs call in Ajax in https (with certificate).
A short time ago I renewed this certificate for my domain and from that moment the app stopped working.

I read this: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#Blacklisting

That Android can block my calls? I ended up in the blacklist? How do I check this?

NOTE: The same app for the iPhone has remained functional. For this reason I think it is the only cause.

Comment: Are you able to confirm if all intermediate certificates are sent by the server during the handshake? You can check this using SSL Labs (ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) or What's My Chain Cert? (whatsmychaincert.com).

Comment: the report : https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?viaform=on&d=https%3A%2F%2Fbackoffice.adria-web.com%2F

Comment: As I suspected... The certificate chain is incomplete. Using What's my Cert provides the correct chain (https://whatsmychaincert.com/generate?host=backoffice.adria-web.com). Deploy this on your domain and Android apps should be able to validate trust.

Comment: Since this is a good solution , if you insert it in the answer I'll accept it . Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SSL Labs Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=backoffice.adria-web.com) indicates that the server is sending an incomplete certificate chain for this domain. You can use [What's My Chain Cert?](https://whatsmychaincert.com/generate?host=backoffice.adria-web.com) to obtain the correct chain that needs to be sent by your server and Android apps should be able to validate trust.

As for why this worked in iOS and not in Android, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222877/ios-allowed-invalid-certificate-while-android-did-not/33226837#33226837).

[image: SSL Labs Server Test result for backoffice.adria-web.com indicating incomplete certificate chain]