# How can I add certificate chain to netty server?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, netty

I bought certificate (from comodo) for my domain, it contains 3 file: private key, certificate, and ca-bundle file.

I add it to my apache server/mod_ssl it work perfectly. I can easy config because it has 3 config param: SSLCertificateFile, SSLCertificateKeyFile, SSLCertificateChainFile.

I'm trying to add to my other java application, using Netty as networking library.
Following is my server code:

```
SslContext sslContext = null;
File cert = new File(Config.CERT_FILE_PATH);
File key = new File(Config.KEY_FILE_PATH);
sslContext = SslContextBuilder.forServer(cert, key).build();
ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
        .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
        .localAddress(port)
        .childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)
        .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
        .childHandler(new WebServerInitializer(sslCtx));
Channel ch = b.bind().sync().channel();
```

With `Config.CERT_FILE_PATH` is my certificate file path, `Config.KEY_FILE_PATH` is my private key file path.

But problem is some browser say certificate error (more detail is Chrome on mac os, browser not trust my certificate).

I did some research and found my netty http server did not send full certificate chain to client (contain Intermediate certificate for my certificate), it only send my certificate only (I exam by KeyStore Explorer tool).

I try replace `Config.CERT_FILE_PATH` value to path of ca-bundle file or append value of certificate file to ca-bundle file and use the new file but still not luck.  An exception was threw:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: decrypt_error
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:358)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:230)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: decrypt_error
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1646)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1614)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1780)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1075)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:901)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:775)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1135)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1025)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:965)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
        ... 12 more
```

How can I add my certificate with ca-bundle to netty server properly?

And why other browser (all browser on windows and mac except chromium base browser on mac) still work with my error server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How exactly did you concatenate the files? If you site if public, I suggest visiting [What's My Chain Cert?](https://whatsmychaincert.com) and downloading the correct chain (keep "Include Root Certificate" unchecked). Use this file as your `cert`.

As for why the site works in most browsers and not in some, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222877/ios-allowed-invalid-certificate-while-android-did-not/33226837#33226837).

You can use [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) to diagnose any certificate and SSL related issues.

Comment: I concat these cert in wrong order, proper order is my cert server before cert chain